# how to go to first position in a listview when I refresh collection in a MAUI application?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a MAUI application with a ListView. This items are binded to a ObservableCollection in my view model.

In my view model I have this code to refresh the collection:

```
private void Refresh(IEnumerable<MyType> paramItems)
{
    MyCollection.Clear();

    foreach (MyType iterator in paramItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.MyDate))
    {
        MyCollection.Add(iterator);
    }
}
```

The problem is that if the user scroll the list view  to see the last items, when I refresh the collection, the position of the scroll is in the same position. I would like that the scroll go to the top, to show the first item.

Thanks.

Comment: You need a custom IEnumerable<T> class and modify the MoveNext() method.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-8.0&force_isolation=true.  current needs to be the first index of the array and method needs to return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maui ListView has a [ScrollTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/listview?view=net-maui-7.0#scroll-an-item-into-view) method. You could use this method to scroll to the first item.

So after you update your ObservableCollection, you could tell the ListView to scroll to the first item position. Here I use  [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-7.0) or you could use [WeakReferenceMessenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger) but you have to install [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm).

```
private void Refresh(IEnumerable<MyType> paramItems)
{
    MyCollection.Clear();

    foreach (MyType iterator in paramItems.OrderByDescending(x => x.MyDate))
    {
        MyCollection.Add(iterator);
    }
    // I get the first item in Collection
    MyType item = MyCollection[0];
    MessagingCenter.Send<MainPageViewModel,MyType>(this, "Hi",item);
}
```

And in the MainPage.cs, we should subscribe this message:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = new MainPageViewModel();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPageViewModel,MyType>(this, "Hi", (sender,Item) =>
    {       
        //we set the x:Name="mylistview" for ListView in xaml
        mylistview.ScrollTo(Item, ScrollToPosition.Start,false);
    });
}
```

If you use WeakReferenceMessenger, that is almost the same,

send the message:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new MyMessage(item));
```

receive the message:

```
    WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<MyMessage>(this, (r, item) =>
    {
        mylistview.ScrollTo(item.Value, ScrollToPosition.Start, false);
    });
```

Hope it works for you.